# Pass JavaScript variable into an embedded HTML object

Tags: javascript, html, variables, object

I have a simple page `index.htm` shown below...

The data attribute of the object will be another external HTML page `test.htm` and is set via the script of the page.

However, `test.htm` runs some script with variables. For example `var x = 123`.

What I want to know is, can I have some script within `index.htm` to change `var x` in the embedded `test.htm` page??

Thanks in advance, George

test.htm

```
<table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
   hello world
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
var x = 123;
</script>
```

index.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>index</title>
</head>
<body>

<object id="page" width='100%' height=700px data="test.htm"></object>

<script>
alert(x)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. According to

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

it should work. Quote:

"A global variable has global scope: All scripts and functions on a web page can access it." Of course your `var x` must not be in a function inside your `test.htm`

Comment: I have created a variable in `test.htm` called `x` and then try `alert(x)` in the `index.htm` file and I get nothing?? @bash.d

Comment: Have you initialized your `x`? What is the actual outcome? `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: Neither, I get absolutely nothing!

Comment: Have you put a `;` at the end of your line? Please paste your script code for test.htm

Comment: Please see above @bash.d

Comment: You cannot place `html` or `body` twice in an HTML file, this won't work. Extract the content of `body` from test.htm and additionally, putting your script BETWEEN body and head doesn't work either! Put it either in the head or body.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have made the changes you suggested (see edited question) and still nothing from `alert(x)`?!

Comment: Okay - I have removed the `<body>` from `test.htm` and still get nothing from `alert(x)`. Perhaps you may be thinking of `document.write`? Or I may be completely wrong.

Comment: Have you debugged the script? Have you checked if the merged HTML makes sense to what you expect?

Comment: Then this won't work. You must have your scripts and HTML in the same scope (at runtime)

Comment: Well that was my original question!

Comment: Sorry, but this wasn't clear to me. According to w3 schools it should work.

Comment: That's okay, can you suggest another way to do this other than an object?? @bash.d